# Upper Case in VB 6 text box

Tags: vba, vb6, vb6-migration

How to make first letter in upper case while pressing tab or space in `vb 6.0` ?

My code is as follows

```
txtFirstName.Text = UCase$(txtFirstName.Text)
```

but it doesn't change after tab or space

Comment: What's the use of the `$` sign?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK it is old-school VB6 syntax.  VB6 did not have a native means to change just the first letter.  Also we have no idea where the code is located or how (or even if)  it is invoked.

Comment: @Plutonix It's not really about old-school syntax. String functions in VB6 exist in pairs - one accepts and returns `Variant`s, the other one accepts and returns `String`s. The strongly typed ones end with `$`. Both are useful in different contexts, so if you have a string variable to begin with, it's better to use `UCase$` than `UCase`.

Comment: @GSerg,  `RTrim$`, `UCase$` etc are actually *very* old school dating back to ROM Basic.  The non type specifier variety (`UCase`) are relative newcomers (VB5 or 6).  But both versions take and return strings.  Maybe vba or  something else uses variant, but not VB6.  From Object browser (which has both defs): `Function UCase(String)
...Returns the specified string, converted to uppercase`

Comment: @Plutonix `String` here is the name of the parameter, not the type. When the type is `Variant`, the Object Browser omits it completely. Compare with `UCase$(String As String)`. Also note there is no return type for `UCase(String)`, again that means the return type is omitted because it's `Variant`. The other one is `UCase$(String As String) As String`. Same thing happens in VBA. But you are right that the dollar sign itself originates from very long time ago.

Comment: @GSerg   The MSDN entry for VBA's UCase is different than VB6 SP3 Object Browser entry (`Returns the specified string...`).  Whether you use UCase or UCase$ VB6 allows a Date, String, Variant or integer to be passed.  The return for both is *normally* a string (VarType vbString).  But if you Type the return variable (`s% = UCase$()) VB6 would perform a type conversion (not unlike Option Infer...gone wild).  Because of the weak typing, there was always unseen conversions about.  There might be a way to force a variant return/assignment, but it usually is vbString.

Comment: @Plutonix `Returns the specified string` really means "Returns the specified string in a Variant/String". The wording is simple in order to not confuse those VB users who don't want to know details. Yes, VB6 is all about implicit conversions, and you can pass almost anything, but before the argument reaches the function, it is converted to a string or a variant. Same with the return type, you can assign a variant to a string anytime, so you can do that with the function result too. That however doesn't change the fact that one returns a `String` and the other one a `Variant/String`.

Comment: In fact, the easiest way is to check the VB6 type library: `[entry(30), helpcontext(000F6EAB)] BSTR _stdcall _B_str_UCase([in] BSTR String); [entry(31), helpcontext(000F659B)] VARIANT _stdcall _B_var_UCase([in] VARIANT* String);`.

Comment: @GSerg Yes, the implementation details are different.  But in the immediate window, `? vartype(UCase(42))` or `? vartype(UCase("foo"))`  or even a date literal prints 8  indicating vbString is returned *before* any assignment conversion can happen.  They are not the same function, but they are functionally the same and interchangeable (even passed a Variant, it comes back as String).  It looks like they were trying to use the new Variant in place of whatever type conversions were needed with the old method.  It hardly matters with such a relic.  Sorry to the OP for the hijack!

Comment: @Plutonix `VarType` is a regular function, not a language construct, and it is declared to accept a parameter of type `VARIANT*`, so the compiler has to pack the true String returned by `UCase$` into a `Variant/String` before passing it to `VarType`, which makes `VarType(UCase("a"))` to appear exactly the same as `VarType(UCase$("a"))`. Yes, they are absolutely interchangeable, but the difference may become important for big strings, because this variant-string conversion creates copies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just simple just do this in the text box keypress events...

```
Private sub textbox_keypress(KeyAscii As Integer)
      KeyAscii = Asc(UCase(Chr(KeyAscii)))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StrConv Function


Returns a Variant (String) converted as specified. 

Syntax

StrConv(string, conversion, LCID)

The StrConv function syntax has these named arguments:

Part Description 
string Required. String expression to be converted. 
conversion Required. Integer. The sum of values specifying the type of conversion to perform. 
LCID Optional. The LocaleID, if different than the system LocaleID. (The system LocaleID is the default.) 


Settings

The conversion argument settings are:

Constant Value Description 
vbUpperCase 1 Converts the string to uppercase characters. 
vbLowerCase 2 Converts the string to lowercase characters. 
vbProperCase 3 Converts the first letter of every word in string to uppercase. 

AND THERE IS MORE ...
```

**TO GSERGE**

$ means nothing when applied to a function name as opposed to a variable name. VBA uses $ AND B as a suffix to denote similar functionality.

**VB6 IS VBA** the person who said *maybe in VB6 but not in VBA*. VB6 program host VBA as their programming language. VB6 on it's own are some app objects and the forms package only - no programming language. It's best to think of VB6 as a VBA host like Office.

If you want to proper case see this WORDBASIC Ver 6 code, (which word 2003 helpfully converted to vba).

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
Public Sub MAIN()
Select Case WordBasic.Int(GetModifer)
        Case 0
                WordBasic.ChangeCase
        Case 1
                WordBasic.ChangeCase 4
        Case 2
                WordBasic.ChangeCase 2
        Case 3
                ProperCase
        Case Else
                WordBasic.ChangeCase
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub ProperCase()
Dim F
Dim z
Dim a$
Dim P
F = 1
WordBasic.ChangeCase 2
WordBasic.EditBookmark Name:="SerenityChangeCase", SortBy:=0, Add:=1
z = WordBasic.GetSelEndPos()
WordBasic.CharLeft 1
        While WordBasic.GetSelEndPos() < z And Not WordBasic.AtEndOfDocument()
                WordBasic.SelectCurWord
                a$ = WordBasic.[Selection$]()
                P = 0
                If LCase(a$) = "a" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "an" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "as" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "at" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "be" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "by" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "in" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "is" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "of" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "on" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "or" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "to" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "and" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "are" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "for" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "the" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "from" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "what" Then
                        P = 1
                ElseIf LCase(a$) = "with" Then
                        P = 1
                End If
                If P = 1 And F = 0 Then WordBasic.Insert LCase(a$)
                WordBasic.WordRight 1
                F = 0
        Wend
WordBasic.WW7_EditGoTo Destination:="SerenityChangeCase"
WordBasic.EditBookmark Name:="SerenityChangeCase", SortBy:=0, Delete:=1
End Sub

Private Function GetModifer()
Dim a
Dim B
Dim c
Dim X
        a = GetAsyncKeyState(16)
        B = GetAsyncKeyState(17)
        c = GetAsyncKeyState(18)
        X = 0
        If a < 0 Then X = X + 1
        If B < 0 Then X = X + 2
        If c < 0 Then X = X + 4
GetModifer = X
End Function
```

Comment: `vbProperCase` will change all first letters, not *the* first letter.

Comment: The text only has one word in it. Read the whole question, it's someone's first name.

Comment: I read the whole question and I did not find "the text only has one word" in it. At the same time I am aware of multi-word last names where not all words must be uppercase (e.g. "der").

Comment: `txtFirstName` was the clue

Comment: @GSerg VERY SILENT AREN'T YOU

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LostFocus` event

```
Private Sub yourTextBox_LostFocus()
    With yourTextBox
        'first letter in upper case, the rest, untouched.
        .Text = UCase(Mid(.Text, 1, 1)) & Mid(.Text, 2, Len(.Text))
    End With
End Sub
```

Apply the same logic to the `KeyDown` event and check if the pressed key is the space key.

```
Private Sub yourTextBox_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 32 Then
        With yourTextBox
            'first letter in upper case, the rest, untouched.
            .Text = UCase(Mid(.Text, 1, 1)) & Mid(.Text, 2, Len(.Text))
            .SelStart = Len(.Text) 'put the cursor at the end of the textbox...
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.  Yeah txtFirstName is a good indicator of usage here.. So I'd use  (sort of) Title Caps And I'd do it on the Validate event.. So

```
Private Sub txtFirstName_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim p As Integer ' i doubt we'll use more than 32K for a name....
    Dim mName As String
    p = 1
    ' first off lets trim any leading blanks.. assume NOTHING and make sure its all lower case..
    mName = LCase(LTrim(txtFirstName))
    Do While p > 0 And p <= Len(txtFirstName) ' start with the first non-blank
        
        Mid(mName, p, 1) = UCase(Mid(mName, p, 1))
        p = InStr(p, mName, " ")
        If p > 0 And p < Len(mName) Then p = p + 1
    Loop
    Cancel = False
    txtFirstName = mName
End Sub
```

Works every time, and capitalizes each word.. Didn't add any code to to do TRUE title caps but this is close, and short & easy...